# Redefinition of 'expect'

Tags: javascript, jshint, chai

I am running jshint and getting this error:

> line 6  col 5  Redefinition of 'expect'.

for this line of code:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
```

Does this mean that expect is a reserved keyword somewhere? I don't see the keyword defined anywhere else in my project and when I remove it from the tests, the tests say:

> expect is not defined

How can this jshint error be fixed?

Comment: try `window.expect = require('chai').expect;`. Does that return any error?

Comment: in strict mode you are not allowed to declare a variable more than once.

Comment: @DanielCheung this is a server side test and I do not have access to the window object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [JSLint documentation](https://jslinterrors.com/redefinition-of-a) for this particular error shows that it is generated when you try to declare a variable with an identifier that is the same as a built-in, native object. This can lead to confusion as people likely expect the built-in, native object and your custom defined one.

The simple solution is: use another identifier.

The other solution is to let JSLint not consider `expect` as a global identifier. You can do that by putting the following in your `.jshintrc` file:

```
"globals": {
    "expect": true
}
```

Comment: Expect true does not get rid of this error for me :(

Comment: This works and is what I was trying to achieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if your JSHint configuration defines `expect` in its `globals` array.

Remove that, since you specifically *aren't* relying on it being a pre-existing global.

Comment: Tried removing it, adding expect: false and expect: true. In all cases, the error is still there.